# angular 6, forms, button click calculation

Tags: angular, forms, button

I am experimenting with angular...  and I need some assitance...

**<<   first Item    >>**
In this example, I want to read the input value **i04Withdraw**, do some arithmetic then display to **this.i03AvailFunds** on the html site. but I cannot figure out how to get the value from the input screen.
The input is suppose to be i04Withdraw

I just want to subtract 10 from **i04Withdraw** and repost the result to i03AvailFunds

this.i03AvailFunds = this.i02WithDraw - 10

**<<  Second Item   >>**
The input field i04Withdraw is a number.  I would lke to add some kind of input mask on it like this...   $0.00
so there is validation for.
- number keys
- and the screen will automatically do something like...    $2000.00

<<------------------------  c001.component.ts -----

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-c001',
  templateUrl: './c001.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./c001.component.css']
})
export class C001Component implements OnInit {

  // sAccount:'TED',
  // email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
  // i01LOC: 100,
  // i02Ballance: 0,
  // i03AvailFunds: 0,
  // i04Withdraw: [0, [Validators.required, Validators.min(200)]]

  sAccount = 'TED'
  i01LOC = 1000
  i02Ballance = 0
  i03AvailFunds = 1000
  i04Withdraw = 0

  myForm: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

   ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      sAccount:'frfrfrf',
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      i01LOC: 100,
      i02Ballance: 0,
      i03AvailFunds: 0,
      i04Withdraw: [0, [Validators.required, Validators.min(200)]]
    })

    this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(console.log)
  }


  recalc(){
//---------   This is where I am trying to do the calculation
    console.log(" hi there i01LOC.value")
    this.i02Ballance += 10
    this.i03AvailFunds = this.i04Withdraw
  }
}
```

<<-----------------------  c001.component.html

```
 <mat-card class="example-card">
  <mat-card-header>
    <!-- <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div> -->
    <!-- <mat-card-title>Extra Credit</mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-subtitle>The Example</mat-card-subtitle> -->
  </mat-card-header>
  <!-- <img mat-card-image src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu"> -->
  <mat-card-content>

    <form [formGroup]="myForm">
      <div>
        Value: {{ myForm.value | json }}
    </div>
      <p>Account ID :{{ sAccount }}</p>
      <p>i01Line Of Credit : {{ i01LOC }}</p>
      <p>i02Ballance : {{ i02Ballance }}</p>
      <p>i03Available Funds : {{ i03AvailFunds }}</p>
          <input formControlName="i04Withdraw">
      <button mat-raised-button (click)="recalc()" color="primary">SUBMIT REQUEST</button>
     </form>

   </mat-card-content>
  <mat-card-actions>
    <!-- <button mat-button>LIKE</button>
    <button mat-button>SHARE</button> -->
  </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

Comment: Try something like this `this.form.controls['i03AvailFunds'].setValue(this.i04Withdraw);`

Answer (score 0):

For the << first Item >>
 You need to access the reactive form value, using for your case:
 `this.myForm.value` for the whole form.value or
 `this.myForm.controls.i04Withdraw.value` in the `recalc()` funtion

example change this.i03AvailFunds value with the input from the form when u click on the mat-button:

```
recalc(){
    this.i03AvailFunds = (this.myForm.controls.i04WithDraw.value - 10) 
}
```

For the << Second Item >> 
For me the best thing you can do is adding a prepend icon to the imput whit the dollar sign otherwise you will have to work with a string with a $ instead of a number.